# How does taskExecutor with Queue size set work with AcceptOnceFileListFilter filter for file input adapter

Tags: spring-integration

From what I understand

1. If you have taskExecutor with 10 pool size and 50 queue size, in the situation where all threads are occupied and the queue is full and I don't set a caller policy, I think the default caller is abort policy which rejects the new polling files when full.

But, if I set my poll fixed rate to 2000 and max-message-per-poll=10, does that mean once the queue has space, it will essentially "retry" the aborted file/task or it won't since I'm using AcceptOnceFileListFilter (Since not sure if rejected task means it was accepted once already)

**What I need to happen:** I have a input file adapter that is polling a directory and processing .txt files received from an MQ. If the thread pool + queue is full, then it should wait till current processing is finished then keep on adding more as threads/queues are become free. (I'm using Spring Integration xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task executor cannot accept new tasks, then no any new files are polled and no interaction with that `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Therefore it is like retry on each poll, but not per file and rather for the whole command as a task per se.